# How do I invalidate the old images when request for a new one is initiated in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Have a look my code below, I have create a pen for it too: https://codepen.io/segmentationfaulter/pen/YEEaxK

The problem is that when I click on `change image` button, the old image stays there for a while until the new image is loaded. What I want is that the old image is invalidated straight away and empty space is shown for the new image. How can I achieve this in react? If you can't spot the issue, try opening it in private mode so that caching doesn't affect it.

```js
const images = [
  'http://via.placeholder.com/550x550',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/750x750'
]

class MyImage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      currentImageIndex: 0
    }
  }
  changeImage() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      if (prevState.currentImageIndex) {
        return {
          currentImageIndex: 0
        }
      } else {
        return {
          currentImageIndex: 1
        }
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      img src = {
        this.props.images[this.state.currentImageIndex]
      }
      /> <
      button onClick = {
        this.changeImage.bind(this)
      } >
      change image <
      /button> <
      /div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < MyImage images = {
      images
    }
    />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
}

button {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div>
```

Comment: This is the browser caching and loading issue as there are no API calls while changing the image. Lazy loading the image should solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47350400/2648216, This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assign a random `key` prop to the img element every time it switches to another image. This forces react to recreate the element.

```
constructor () {
  super()
  this.state = {
    currentImageIndex: 0,
    imgKey: Math.random()
  }
}
changeImage () {
   this.setState((prevState) => {
     if (prevState.currentImageIndex) {
       return { currentImageIndex: 0, imgKey: Math.random() }
     } else {
       return { currentImageIndex: 1, imgKey: Math.random() }
     }
   })
 }

render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <img key={this.state.imgKey} src={this.props.images[this.state.currentImageIndex]} />
        <button onClick={this.changeImage.bind(this)}>
          change image
        </button>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure whether key would help this because `key` should be used to mount the whole component again. This is more of a browser issue than re-rendering or mounting issue.

Comment: I agree this is a browser issue. I tried OP's CodePen and cannot reproduce the issue in all of my installed browsers on my Mac. But based on his description, recreating the img element should achieve what he wants. Based on this [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), assigning a different `key` should cause the element being recreated, not re-mounted.

Comment: Both the images must be getting cached in the browser and yeah changing the key re-mounts the whole component

Answer (score 1):

You could use, for example, `onLoad` prop from `img` where you toggle a `loading` in state so you can render the placeholder.

The strategy around it is:

- display the placeholder and *hide* the image if `loading` is `true`
- hide the loading when the image has been loaded.

PS: I added a timeout so you can see the placeholder in action.

```js
const images = [
  'http://via.placeholder.com/550x550',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/750x750'
]

class Images extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      currentImageIndex: 0,
      loading: true,
    }
  }

  handleLoad() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ loading: false })
    }, 1000)
  }
  
  changeImage() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      if (prevState.currentImageIndex) {
        return {
          currentImageIndex: 0
        }
      }
      return {
        currentImageIndex: 1
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, currentImageIndex } = this.state
    
    return (
      <div>
        {loading && <div>placeholder comes here</div>}
        <img
          onLoad={this.handleLoad.bind(this)}
          src={images[currentImageIndex]}
          style={{ display: loading ? 'none' : 'block' }}
        />
        <button onClick={this.changeImage.bind(this)}>
          change image
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Images />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible way may be:

1. put empty picture if state is changed
2. fetch the image and then replace empty image from response